# How can I use powershell to intercept a specified string of a command output?

Tags: powershell

I use ipptool to get the status of the current print job.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ipptool http://localhost/ipp/printers get-completed-jobs.test


job-id job-state job-name job-originating-user-name job-media-sheets-completed

------ --------- -------- ------------------------- --------------------------

14     canceled                RedHat                    1

13     completed               RedHat                    1

12     completed               RedHat                    1

11     completed               RedHat                    1
```

How do I get the specified job-id and job-state?

What method does Powershell use to intercept strings?

Question 1:

Get the following string：

14          canceled

Question 2 :

Get the following string:

13     completed

12     completed

Question 3 :

How do I get the most recent job-id and job-state?

Comment: What is the most recent job-id? Last in the list, highest job-id number?

Comment: highest job-id number

Comment: After using @iRon's function `$Jobs | Sort $job-id -desc |select -First 1`

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

The cmdlet [**`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable)  available for download from the [`PowerShell gallery`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) ([GitHub: `iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable)) is capable of reading this type of data tables:

```
$Jobs = ConvertFrom-SourceTable '

job-id job-state job-name job-originating-user-name job-media-sheets-completed

------ --------- -------- ------------------------- --------------------------

14     canceled                RedHat                    1

13     completed               RedHat                    1

12     completed               RedHat                    1

11     completed               RedHat                    1
'
```

In your case, it is probably something like:

```
$Jobs = $(.\ipptool http://localhost/ipp/printers get-completed-jobs.test) | ConvertFrom-SourceTable
```

The rest of your questions are actually a matter of basic PowerShell commands.
As in this example, the `Jobs` object will give you access to e.g. the status of job 14:

```
$Jobs | ?{$_."job-id" -eq 14} | Select -Expand "job-state"
canceled
```

And "*How do I get the most recent job-id and job-state?*":
<sub>(presuming that the most recent job is always on top)</sub>

```
$Jobs | Select  "job-id", "job-state" -First 1

job-id job-state
------ ---------
14     canceled
```

<sub>(For other `ConvertFrom-SourceTable` examples see: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ConvertFrom-SourceTable)</sub>

Comment: Nice one +1. Is there a way to retain the original property order?

Comment: @LotPings, no (except from: `| Select "job-id", "job-state", "job-name", "job-originating-user-name", "job-media-sheets-completed"`) but I will give it some thought for the next version.

Comment: How can I install ConvertFrom-SourceTable  cmdlet ?                                                
I already dowload  ConvertFrom-SourceTable-master.zip  from  https://github.com/iRon7/ConvertFrom-SourceTable  .   After decompressing  ConvertFrom-SourceTable-master.zip  ，I  can see  ConvertFrom-SourceTable.ps1 。 Where should I put this file in order to use this command in powershell?

Comment: @Andrew8460958, just [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the script (like: `. .\ConvertFrom-SourceTable.ps1`) to use/include it.

Comment: @LotPings, I have uploaded a new version ([0.0.42](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable/0.0.42/DisplayScript)) that retains the original property order.

Comment: Good job, well done. Was about to complain, but had forgotten to re-dot-source.